# Code::blocks does not find the SDL_FreeTexture command from the sdl library

Tags: c++, g++, codeblocks, sdl-2

i am trying to make a siple "PickStick" game to learn sdl2 with c++. Everything works fine I can create window, load texture, create rendere, etc... but when I try to use the command `sdl_FreeTexture("the texture name here");` the compiler/code::blocks simply does not find it in the library and output

> Error : 'SDL_FreeTexture' was not declared in this scope

Comment: And you're _sure_ SDL has a function called `SDL_FreeTexture`. I know there's [`SDL_DestroyTexture`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_DestroyTexture?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAPI%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29)....

Comment: pretty sure look at this link : http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=9493&sid=31c8c5008bc96ed3a7cbb18eccb7d3aa

Comment: nevermind i just found the answer

Comment: I just had to use SDL_DestroyTexture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:
`SDL_DestroyTexture("the texture name here");`